# No idea what I'm doing with IntentIntegrator

Tags: java, android, zxing

I'm having trouble getting zxing to do anything after scanning a barcode. I call the zxing using:

`IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(MainActivity.this);`

And my onActivityResult looks like this

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            if (format == "PRODUCT_CODE"){
                //If the barcode scanned is of the correct type then pass the barcode into the search method to get the product details
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You scanned " + contents, 3).show();
            }
            else{
                //If the barcode is not of the correct type then display a notification
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You didn't scan a product code", 3).show();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //If the scan is cancelled then display a notification
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You cancelled the input", 3).show();
        }
    }
```

}

But whenever I exit zxing nothing is displayed. I tried using the example [in the zxing wiki](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent)
 but whenever I try to replace yourActivity with MainActivity or MainActivity.this I receive errors (I get told MainActivity cannot be resolved to a string and with MainActivity.this that The constructor IntentIntegrator(MainActivity) is undefined).

Basically I have no idea what I'm doing and why it's not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly the same as in your other question. You can't compare strings with `==`, but must use `equals()`.